# How to pass a value from form submit to pug email template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a form posting to /submit-form route and I need to pass req.body.revenue value to be used in the email template that goes out after the form submit.

```
        const email = req.body.email;
        const revenue = req.body.revenue;

        // Prepare the nodemailer
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
            port: 587,
            secure: false,
            tls: { cipers: 'SSLv3' },
            auth: {
                user: 'postmaster@sandbox.mailgun.org',
                pass: 'xyz',
            }
        });

        // Prepare the email data
        const data = {
            from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
            to: email,
            subject: 'Hello Pixel, Where those cookies at?',
            text: 'Gonna load the pixel next in the HTML',
            html: { path: 'pixel-tracker-email.html' }
        };

        // Send the mail via Nodemailer
        transporter.sendMail(data)
            .then(msg => console.log(msg))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
            console.log('Email sent via Nodemailer!');
```

I have pug set up for my email template and have tried changing the html value to something like this:

```
// Prepare the email data
        const data = {
            from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
            to: email,
            subject: 'Hello Pixel, Where those cookies at?',
            text: 'Gonna load the pixel next in the HTML',
            html: var html = pug.renderFile('path/to/email-template.pug', {revenue});
        };
```

And then I'm using #{revenue} in the actual email-template.pug file but the value isn't coming through.

Comment: Can you show us your pug template ? Is `revenue` an object or a primitive ?

Comment: It seems that a syntax error is present in `html: var html = pug.renderFile('path/to/email-template.pug', {revenue})`. Can we declare a variable while creating an object ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out like this

```
html: pug.renderFile(__dirname + '/views/tracking.pug', { email: email, revenue: revenue })
```